# Netsuite schedule script saved search

Tags: javascript, scheduled-tasks, netsuite, suitescript, saved-searches

```
/**
* @NApiVersion 2.x
* @NScriptType ScheduledScript
* @NModuleScope SameAccount
*/
define(['N/search','N/record','N/file'],

function(search,record,file) {

/**
 * Definition of the Scheduled script trigger point.
 *
 *@param {search} search
 *@param {record} record
 *@param {file} file
 * @param {Object} scriptContext
 * @param {string} scriptContext.type - The context in which the script is executed. It is one of the values from the scriptContext.InvocationType enum.
 * @Since 2015.2
 */
function execute(context) {

    var currentdate=new Date().getTime();
    var arr=[];
    arr.push(currentdate);


    for(i in arr){
        if(arr.length==1){
            var cmpdate=arr[i];
        }
        var cmpdate=arr[i--];
    }

    var sosearch=search.create({type:search.Type.TRANSACTION,
        filters:[
                ['type',search.Operator.ANYOF,'SalesOrd'],'and',
                ['mainline',search.Operator.IS,true],'and',
                ['formuladate',search.Operator.AFTER,cmpdate]                   
                ],
    columns:['salesoreder']

    });

  var searchresult=sosearch.run().each(function(result) {
        var soid= result.getValue({
            name: 'internalid'
});
  });

  for(r in searchresult){
      var sorec=record.load({type:'salesorder',id:searchresult[r]});
      var myfile=file.create({name:maqsofile,fileType:file.Type.CSV,contents:sorec})
      myfile.folder=520;
      myfile.save();
  }    
}
return {
    execute: execute
};

});
```

**I am trying to perform a saved search so that whenever a  script is triggered i get the sales orders that were created within that time period(eg: within every 30m) after this i will create files of this sales order.the idea over here is that  comparing the creation date of last run  record with the current date time then this current time will be compared with next current date time for next run but the problem is that iam unable to compare the formats of dates i.e. new Date() with the date iam trying to use in saved search creation.  **

Comment: In search creation for value of current date time iam using a variable cmpdate that i have retrieved from an array that stores the previous current datetimes.

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation would be to create a script parameter on your scheduled script, e.g. custscript_last_search_thru_date. Then update the parameter after the search is run, so it could be used as the start date the next time the script runs.

```
var searchStartDate = runtime.getCurrentScript().getParameter({name: 'custscript_last_search_thru_date'});
var searchEndDate=new Date();

filters.push(search.createFilter({
    name: 'datecreated',
    operator: search.Operator.AFTER,
    values: searchStartDate.getTime()
}));

filters.push(search.createFilter({
    name: 'datecreated',
    operator: search.Operator.ONORBEFORE,
    values: searchEndDate.getTime()
}));

// Run search and do stuff

record.submitFields({
    type: 'scriptdeployment',
    id: deploymentId,
    values: {
        custscript_last_search_thru_date : searchEndDate
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks  a lot kevin for investing your time to solve my issue. it helped a lot but one more thing I want to ask you is that for setting the script parameter value via suitescipt the method you havew give i.e. record.submitField(..) is not working can you help me with that

Comment: What is happening? Are you getting an error? Have you set up your script parameter with type of DateTime and is it set up to store value?

Comment: its set to type dateTime only but through a script how can we set a value for script parameter because your above mentioned method i.e. record.submitField(..) isn't working its not setting the value for the script parameter

Comment: Also, are you referencing the deployment record by its NUMERIC ID when you call record.submitFields? The function is not set up to accept the deployment's script ID, e.g. customdeploy_this_will_break.

Comment: I tried with both the id's  i.e. numeric as well as the custom one but it aint working.I found on netsuite help center that we cant set a value for script parameter from a script.therefore,I've used a custom record type for this task and now my issue is solved .still thanks alot kevin.

Comment: I see the issue in my answer and fixed. Notice where I moved the .getTime() function. The script deployment parameter will update when the date/time object is formatted correctly.